# hex header of file, magic numbers, python

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, header, hex

I have a program in Python which analyses file headers and decides which file type it is. (https://github.com/LeoGSA/Browser-Cache-Grabber)

The problem is the following:
I read first 24 bytes of a file:

```
with open (from_folder+"/"+i, "rb") as myfile:
    header=str(myfile.read(24))
```

then I look for pattern in it:

```
if y[1] in header:
    shutil.move (from_folder+"/"+i,to_folder+y[2]+i+y[3])
```

where `y = ['/video', r'\x47\x40\x00', '/video/', '.ts']`

`y[1]` is the pattern and = `r'\x47\x40\x00'`

the file has it inside, as you can see from the picture below.

[image]

the program does NOT find this pattern (r'\x47\x40\x00') in the file header.

so, I tried to print header:

[image]

You see? Python sees it as 'G@' instead of '\x47\x40'

and if i search for 'G@'+r'\x00' in header - everything is ok. It finds  it.

Question: What am I doing wrong? I want to look for `r'\x47\x40\x00'` and find it. Not for some strange 'G@'+r'\x00'.

OR

why python sees first two numbers as 'G@' and not as '\x47\x40', though the rest of header it sees in HEX? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: I would write each of this line you read out of the file formatted into HEX to a temp string and then compare the string.

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: Python 3.4.3 And 3.5

Comment: And yes, I found kind of solution doing like this:             with open (from_folder+"/"+i, "rb") as myfile:
                header=myfile.read(24)
                header = str(binascii.hexlify(header))[2:-1]

4740001b0000b00d0001c100000001efff3690e23dffffff

Comment: But I still don't understand why the hack it read first two bytes NOT in HEX

Comment: If you're unclear on how that happened, try `bytes(range(256))` in interactive mode and see what it gives you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    with open (from_folder+"/"+i, "rb") as myfile:
        header=myfile.read(24)
        header = str(binascii.hexlify(header))[2:-1]
```

the result I get is:
And I can work with it

4740001b0000b00d0001c100000001efff3690e23dffffff

P.S. But anyway, if anybody will explain what was the problem with 2 first bytes - I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3 you'll get bytes from a binary read, rather than a string.
No need to convert it to a string by str.
Print will try to convert bytes to something human readable.
If you don't want that, convert your bytes to e.g. hex representations of the integer values of the bytes by:

```
aBytes = b'\x00\x47\x40\x00\x13\x00\x00\xb0'
print (aBytes)
print (''.join ([hex (aByte) for aByte in aBytes]))
```

Output as redirected from the console:

```
b'\x00G@\x00\x13\x00\x00\xb0'
0x00x470x400x00x130x00x00xb0
```

You can't search in `aBytes` directly with the `in` operator, since `aBytes` isn't a string but an array of bytes.

If you want to apply a string search on '\x00\x47\x40', use:

```
aBytes = b'\x00\x47\x40\x00\x13\x00\x00\xb0'
print (aBytes)
print (r'\x'.join ([''] + ['%0.2x'%aByte for aByte in aBytes]))
```

Which will give you:

```
b'\x00G@\x00\x13\x00\x00\xb0'
\x00\x47\x40\x00\x13\x00\x00\xb0
```

So there's a number of separate issues at play here:

- `print` tries to print something human readable, which succeeds only for the first two chars.
- You can't directly search for bytearrays in bytearrays with `in`, so convert them to a string containing fixed length hex representations as substrings, as shown.

Comment: b'\x00G@\x00\x13\x00\x00\xb0'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:\33.py", line 3, in <module>
    print (''.join ([hex (ord (aByte)) for aByte in aBytes]))
  File "I:\33.py", line 3, in <listcomp>
    print (''.join ([hex (ord (aByte)) for aByte in aBytes]))
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, used Python 2.7, have now corrected and tested for 3.5.